# Options for SmoothDensityHistogram

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

I would like to add an option to `SmoothDensityHistogram` about what to plot (PDF, CDF,...). I am using quite a lot of options:

```
 SmoothDensityHistogram[somedata, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
                        BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 34, FontFamily -> "Arial"},
                        FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3]],
                        MeshStyle -> White, Mesh -> 5,
                        PlotLegends ->   Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {0, 1}},
                        LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.3], 30, FontFamily -> "Arial"},
                        LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5] &)], After]]
```

the question is: where on how should I put the (e.g. `"PDF"`) option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of `SmoothDensityHistogram` is as follows:

```
SmoothDensityHistogram[data_, espec_, dfun_, OptionsPattern[]] := ...
```

As is described in the documentation. Consequently, to specify the distribution without specifying the estimator specification, which seems to be what you want to do, you should do the following:

```
SmoothDensityHistogram[
 somedata,
 Automatic,
 "PDF",
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 34, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3]], 
 MeshStyle -> White,
 Mesh -> 5,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   BarLegend[
    {Automatic, {0, 1}}, 
    LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.3], 30, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5] &)],
   After
   ]
 ]
```

`Automatic` is used to avoid changing the default value of `espec` and `dfun` is set to `"PDF"` and supplied as the third positional argument.